# The imported project "" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, microsoft-dynamics

I'm opening a project in Visual 2015 but I'm getting many errors.  This is one of the errors:

```
C:\Users\Steve\Documents\MyProj\EFT\Connector.Sample\Connector.Sample.Desktop\PaymentSdk.Connector.Sample.Desktop.csproj : error  : The imported project "C:\Users\Steve\Documents\MyProj\EFT\BuildTools\Microsoft.Dynamics.RetailSdk.Build.props" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.  C:\Users\Steve\Documents\MyProj\EFT\Connector.Sample\Connector.Sample.Desktop\PaymentSdk.Connector.Sample.Desktop.csproj
```

When I double-click on it, it takes me to here:

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMIiX.jpg)

What's wrong ? How can I fix the error?

I tried this:

```
msbuild.exe C:\Users\Steve\Documents\MyProj\EFT\Connector.Sample\Connector.Sample\PaymentSdk.Connector.Sample.csproj /p:VisualStudioVersion=14.0
```

but I get this error:

```
C:\Users\Steve\Documents\MyProj\EFT\Connector.Sample\Connector.Sample\PaymentSdk.Connector.Sample.csproj(3,11): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Users\Steve\Documents\MyProj\EFT\BuildTools\Microsoft.Dynamics.RetailSdk.Build.props" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk
```

I'm using Visual Studio 2015.

Thank you.

Comment: Install the Microsoft Dynamics SDK...